# Cython TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not NoneType

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I have a perfectly working python programme, I wanted to make use of Cython for **just one** function inside this programme.

the original function was:

```
def NoFeedB(Ef, Ef2, Nf, u, tijd ):
  dEdt= np.zeros_like(Ef, dtype=np.complex128)
  dNdt= np.zeros_like(Nf)
  Efcon = np.conjugate(Ef)

  for j in xrange(nrModes):
    for n in xrange(nrMoments):
      dEdt = dEdt  +  0.5 * CouplingE((j+1,n,0)) * dg * (1+ A*1j) * Nf[n] * Ef[j] * np.exp( 1j* (sweep.omega[j]-sweep.omega) *tijd)
      for k in xrange(nrModes):
        if n==0:
          dNdt = dNdt + (g* CouplingN((j+1, k+1, 0 )) * Efcon[j] * Ef[k] * np.exp( 1j* (sweep.omega[k]-sweep.omega[j]) *tijd) )
        dNdt = dNdt + ( dg*(1+A*1j) * CouplingN((j+1,k+1,n)) * Nf[n] * Efcon[j] * Ef[k] * np.exp( 1j* (sweep.omega[k]-sweep.omega[j]) *tijd) )

  dEdt = dEdt - 0.5*(pd-g)*Ef 
  dNdt = sweep.Jn - Nf*ed - np.real(dNdt)
  return dEdt, dNdt
```

Looking at these two sites:
http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html#primes
and 
http://docs.cython.org/0.14/src/tutorial/numpy.html I changed the code into this:

```
def NoFeedB( np.ndarray[np.complex128_t,ndim= nrModes] Ef,  np.ndarray[np.complex128_t,ndim= nrModes] Ef2,  np.ndarray[np.complex128_t,ndim= nrMoments]Nf,  np.ndarray[np.float64_t,ndim= nrModes] u,  float tijd ):

  cdef np.ndarray[np.complex128_t,ndim= nrModes] dEdt = np.zeros(nrModes,dtype=np.complex128)
  cdef np.ndarray[np.complex128_t,ndim= nrMoments] dNdt= np.zeros(Nf, float64)

  cdef np.ndarray[np.complex128_t,ndim= nrModes] Efcon = np.conjugate(Ef)

  cdef Py_ssize_t j,n,k

  for j in xrange(nrModes):
    for n in xrange(nrMoments):
      dEdt = dEdt  +  0.5 * CouplingE((j+1,n,0)) * dg * (1+ A*1j) * Nf[n] * Ef[j] * np.exp( 1j* (sweep.omega[j]-sweep.omega) *tijd)
      for k in xrange(nrModes):
        if n==0:
          dNdt = dNdt + (g* CouplingN((j+1, k+1, 0 )) * Efcon[j] * Ef[k] * np.exp( 1j* (sweep.omega[k]-sweep.omega[j]) *tijd) )
        dNdt = dNdt + ( dg*(1+A*1j) * CouplingN((j+1,k+1,n)) * Nf[n] * Efcon[j] * Ef[k] * np.exp( 1j* (sweep.omega[k]-sweep.omega[j]) *tijd) )

  dEdt = dEdt - 0.5*(pd-g)*Ef 
  dNdt = sweep.Jn - Nf*ed - np.real(dNdt)
  return dEdt, dNdt
```

Now I get this error:

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not NoneType
```

can you help me please?

EDIT 1:

Complete Error message: (There is no mention at which line the error is taking place in my functions.pyx file)

```
python setup_functions.py build_ext --inplace
Compiling functions.pyx because it changed.
Cythonizing functions.pyx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup_functions.py", line 6, in <module>
    setup(ext_modules = cythonize("functions.pyx"))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 798, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 898, in cythonize_one
    result = compile([pyx_file], options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 608, in compile
    return compile_multiple(source, options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 586, in compile_multiple
    result = run_pipeline(source, options, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 433, in run_pipeline
    err, enddata = Pipeline.run_pipeline(pipeline, source)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Pipeline.py", line 328, in run_pipeline
    data = phase(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Pipeline.py", line 52, in generate_pyx_code_stage
    module_node.process_implementation(options, result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/ModuleNode.py", line 109, in process_implementation
    self.generate_c_code(env, options, result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/ModuleNode.py", line 326, in generate_c_code
    self.body.generate_function_definitions(env, code)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py", line 394, in generate_function_definitions
    stat.generate_function_definitions(env, code)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py", line 394, in generate_function_definitions
    stat.generate_function_definitions(env, code)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py", line 2861, in generate_function_definitions
    FuncDefNode.generate_function_definitions(self, env, code)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py", line 1798, in generate_function_definitions
    self.generate_function_body(env, code)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py", line 1567, in generate_function_body
    self.body.generate_execution_code(code)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py", line 400, in generate_execution_code
    stat.generate_execution_code(code)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py", line 4519, in generate_execution_code
    self.generate_assignment_code(code)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py", line 4650, in generate_assignment_code
    self.lhs.generate_assignment_code(self.rhs, code)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/ExprNodes.py", line 1984, in generate_assignment_code
    self.generate_acquire_buffer(rhs, code)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/ExprNodes.py", line 2059, in generate_acquire_buffer
    pos=self.pos, code=code)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Buffer.py", line 369, in put_assign_to_buffer
    getbuffer = get_getbuffer_call(code, "%s", buffer_aux, buffer_type) # fill in object below
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Buffer.py", line 343, in get_getbuffer_call
    "%(cast)d, __pyx_stack)" % locals())
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not NoneType
```

Comment: Where do you get the error? (line number and code)

Comment: That error doesn't look like it originates in the code you've shown here.

Comment: I'm guessing here, but maybe this relates to `nrModes` or `nrMoments` which need to be compile-time constants, but look to be being treated as variables. I suspect Cython is doing some string substitution when it generates the C code, and that's where the error is coming from.

Comment: Thank you @DavidW ... You are right. Upon changing all nrModes and nrMoments to literal constants the error dissappeared and build the .c files perfectly.